# Enable USB debugging in an Android broken screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, root-access, fastboot, usb-debugging

I have a broken display which belongs to my friend. The mobile can power on but the display is still blank. I need to enable USB debugging to recover the data. While doing so there are these following .

**Problems:**

1. USB debugging is not enabled
2. Bootloader is locked
3. Mobile has a password (pin or character password)
4. Devevoper options may not be turned on (cant tell now)
5. Devices is not detected via ADB or Fastboot
6. Cant go into the recovery or Fastboot mode
7. Device is not rooted
8. Custom Recovery not installed
9. No SD Card slot

**Terminal Output:**

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ adb devices
List of devices attached

➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ fastboot devices
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗
```

**What I have tried?**

1. Tried Odin and SP Flash tool (Mobile not detected)
2. Tried to enter the recovery and fastboot (No use)
3. Tried ADB in a variety of OS (Win 10, Manjaro, Backbox, Win 7)

So is there any way to enable USB debugging in that device? Or any way of recovering the data. Any small lead that can make this device accessible via a computer is really helpful.

**Note: How this differs from other similar questions:**

Those devices that have this similar problem atleast have USB debugging enabled in the first place. Some can still go to recovery where as I cant. Some have SD card support this phone lacks it.

**Device Description:**

- Manufacturer   : *Micromax*
- Model No.      : *A350*
- Root Status    : *Not rooted*
- Bricked Status : *No*
- Boot Status    : *Boots*
- Recovery       : *Stock*
- USB debugging  : *Not enabled*
- Bootloader     : *Locked*
- Phone Lock     : *Password or Pin*
- Display Status : *Blank black screen*
- USB OTG : *Supported*
- SD Card Support : *No*

Comment: What is the name and model of your cell phone?

Comment: Model: Micromax A350

Comment: @SifaturRahman I have updated the question. Please check the device description for more details. Thank you

Comment: Don't go down that path. Find a custom recovery (both Philz Touch and TWRP exists for this device) and flash it using SP Flash Tool. You don't need an unlocked bootloader or USB debugging enabled for that. You need that software and a [scatter based ROM](https://androidmtk.com/download-micromax-stock-rom-models) for your device. Load the scatter file and flash only the recovery partition with custom recovery. You can Google how to use that software. USB debugging is by-default enabled in a custom recovery.

Comment: So @Firelord you are saying SP Flash tool does not require USB debugging to be enabled ?

Comment: Yes, I mean it. I have used it on that same device back some two-three years ago. USB debugging has no use unless you want to use an adb client. SP Flash Tool is not an adb client.

Comment: Im currently downloading the stock rom. Hoping that I will find the scatter file inside the zip. Will I ?

Comment: Please tag me with @firelord, else I can't know you addressed a comment to me. And yes, you would find that scatter file, that's why I linked that page to your ROM. I must warn you to carefully read and watch tutorials before trying that software. It may severely brick the device if not being careful. But carefully followed, it would do exactly what you want with it.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the info. I will try it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @VimalJoe Download & install the PC suite of Micromax and the usb driver of your cellphone. Then connect your chell phone to the computer and see If you can access your phone memory from the PC suite. Some PC suite may require USB debugging enabled to work though.

Comment: @Firelord I tried all versions of SP Flash Tool. Everything failed to connect. Each returns one of 3 errors. I may be able to flash but the data will be wiped for sure. So is there any other way?

Comment: @SifaturRahman PC suites are during the Nokia era.  Micromax does not have PC Suite of its own. However Moborobo can be used. In my case since ADB is disabled moborobo cant help.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:
Connect keyboard via usb otg and enter password (buy usb otg if you don't have it).
Disconnect keyboard and connect PC, take a screenshot on your phone and load it in the PC. Swap between mouse and PC (mouse to move around some, PC to step by step check how to get there by the screenshots)

Comment: Not a native english speaker so if anything is confusing just ask

Comment: The display doesn't work, so I am not sure how any of this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone with USB to your laptop.
Then open the folder **DCIM –> Screenshots** of your phone with the laptop.

With your phone, open “Settings” and **take a screenshot with your phone physical keys (*e.g. Samsung on Android 10: press VOLUME DOWN + POWER BUTTON very shortly to take a screenshot*) every time you scroll the screen to find “About phone” and “Developer Options” –> USB-debugging**.

**If your screen is unresponsive**, plug an USB keyboard to your phone with an OTG adapter. Then, use the keyboard to open Settings (Android: press the Windows key on the USB-keyboard to activate Google speech recognition and say "settings") and scroll with the arrow keys to About Phone or Developer Options, while taking screenshots every time you scroll with the arrow keys.

**Look at the screenshots on your computer to find the right place to swipe and touch with your finger** (or if you are using OTG+USB keyboard: **find the right amount of arrow key & Enter key presses** to find USB debugging in Developer Options). Refresh the folder every time you take a new screenshot, a new screenshot should appear in the folder in around 5 seconds.

After USB debugging is turned on, connect your phone with USB to your computer and use **scrcpy** (https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to view your phone screen on your laptop computer.

Comment: OP mentioned that **the display is blank and is also broken**. If you connect the device with a PC you have to interact with the screen to enable MTP mode. Also, if the screen is broken than the steps using those screenshots cannot be followed either.

Comment: @Firelord very good point, I missed that. I edited my post a little and included some possible solutions if the screen is unresponsive and swiping/tapping the screen does nothing.

Comment: If you're lucky / sensible-in-a-past-life, then you're default USB mode may not just be charge, but infact file access or MTP mode. Luckily mine was, so thanks for this mad method.